# Adding a page in the end of a document with preamble

Tags: package-writing, preamble

I am working on a special style package for a company and one of templates must include a special blank page in the end of a document. In order to do it I could make a command like `\makeEndPage` that will create my page and always type it before `\end{document}`, but I want to do it automatically in `.sty` file so there will be no need to write anything in `.tex` file at all. Is there any way to do it? Notice that it is not a bibliography

Comment: `\AtEndDocument{\makeEndPage}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found this solution, but I've read somewhere that `\AtEndDocument` include `\end{document}` by itself and that in this case I will have 2 `\end{document}` commands. Is it true or a false information?

Comment: no that's false.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much! Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: Remember the possible floats at the end (so a `\clearpage` might be useful)

Comment: @daleif thank you!